# A term (or phrase) for when a person tries to represent the rarest scenario as the most common

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, vocabulary, politics

For context:

This term or phrase is what it's called when a person (very often used in political debates) will try to take the rarest occurrence of any particular topic and present it as if it's the common practice in order to drive or support their argument. I would liken it to something like "anomaly argument" (except, not completely made up lol). I'll know it when I hear it but for the life of me, I just can't think of it. I hope my poor context helps just a little bit.

Comment: The list linked below suggests: hasty generalization, spotlight fallacy, sweeping generalization, biased generalization, cherrypicking, misleading vividness, suppressed evidence. https://informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/rhetological-fallacies/

Comment: Sounds like "Your example is apocryphal, not representative.

Comment: Probably a duplicate. See [What is a word for deliberate dismissal of some of the facts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355379/what-is-a-word-for-deliberate-dismissal-of-some-facts/355495#355495),  [What word describes interpreting evidence in such a way as to reach a desired conclusion?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/what-word-describes-interpreting-evidence-in-such-a-way-as-to-reach-a-desired-co) I'm not sure that there is an expression highlighting choosing just the rarest non-representative example. In general, it's a 'deliberate sampling error'.

Comment: [philosophy.se] is a better place to ask about fallacies and types of arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestion. I was watching TV today and finally heard someone say it to remind me! The word was : anecdotal

Comment: Unless you add a supporting reference showing a clear connection between 'anecdotal' and 'when a person tries to represent the rarest scenario as the most common', Will, I'm afraid this answer might be downvoted. 'Anecdotal' evidence is (like this answer) not supported by valid statistics/references, and so supports what _may or may not_ be a true claim. There may be a lot of evidence that _could_ be mentioned; 'anecdotal' means 'presented lacking convincing evidence' _not_ 'there _is_ no convincing evidence available'. The scenario mentioned could be common.